# BEGIN AND COMMIT MYSQL EXECUTE JAVA

Tags: mysql, transactions

I have this simple doubt:

```
String sql ="BEGIN;" +
                        "DELETE FROM users WHERE username='gg';" +
                        "DELETE FROM comprofiler WHERE id=611;" +
                        "COMMIT;";


st.execute(sql);
```

Why doesn't it work? It works if it's just one instruction, how can I type this?

Comment: mysql doesn't generally allow multiple statements in a single `query()` call, as a basic defense against one form of [sql injection attack](http://bobby-tables.com).

Comment: put it in a stored proc with parameters. If you can call it via workbench, so can Java. Also use `START TRANSACTION; ` and don't forget extra spaces for padding. So maybe it is an uncaught syntax error.